# Sorting Lists of Lists in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

There is List of Lists. For example

```
{{ 4,  5,  3,  1,  2},
 {14, 15, 13, 11, 12},
 {24, 25, 23, 21, 22}}
```

I need to sort values in these Lists so that values of each List should be ordered based on first List. So the result should be

```
{{ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
 {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
 {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}}
```

What is the best way to do it effectively in Java? I try to think of using Collections.sort in some way, but I have no idea. Any help and advise will be appreciated

**UPD:** Sorry for unclear question, I'll try to clarify. I have matrix and I need to sort columns of the matrix. I should sort them on a specific row (first row in my example). But matrix is represented as List of Lists (not 2-dimensional array). The matrix can be large enough. And I prefer not to implement sorting myself (as I believe Java Collections/Arrays sort() methods do it effectively). As I have already said, matrix can be large, so I don't want to rearrange elements in every List on every step of sorting algorithm.

What I see is to sort only first List an get some permutation (Can I achieve this using sort() method?). Then based on this permutation I want to rearrange other elements in the matrix. But I'm not sure it's a good approach.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you want to sort each list ascendingly? What do you mean by "based on first List"? Also, will there be duplicates in the list?

Comment: I've provide some additional info

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, you want to sort each internal List within the parent List structure. Afterwards, check for order with a custom comparator.

**Sort the Child Lists within the Parent List**

```
 for (List l : parentList) {
     Collections.sort(l); 
 }
```

**Check to make sure the lists are in order**

```
 Collections.sort(parentList, new ListComparator<List<Integer>>())
```

**Custom Comparator to evaluate the 1st index of each List**

```
 public ListComparator extends Comparator<List<Integer>> {

     @Override
     public int compareTo(List<Integer> thisList, List<Integer> thatList) {
         return thisList.get(0).compareTo(thatList.get(0);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections.sort() would be a reasonable way to do it. You would need to implement a custom Comparator object and iterate through your outer list, sorting each of the inner lists. If necessary you could also implement a Comparator for sorting the lists in the outer list.

[This tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/) has a pretty good example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Column Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/). It allows you to sort on any column of the List. So instead of creating a different Comparator for a specify column, you just pass the column as a parameter to the `ColumnComparator`.

The `ColumnComparator` can be used to sort Arrays or Lists.